# Add primary key column to a existing mysqli database table

Tags: mysql

I know how to add a primary key when creating the table, but not how to add it to an existing table. Do I need to create a column and then change the type to a primary key, or use something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table-name MODIFY column-name PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `primary key` the table by;

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD PRIMARY KEY(primary_key_column);
```

If you want `composite primary key`(primary key of more than on column) then,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(column_1, column_2);
```

If you have already a primary key and you want to drop existing and add another 
then,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(primary_key_column);
```